# How to make ticks shows in D3

Tags: d3.js, scale, axis, linechart

I am making a line graph and I can't get all the tick marks to display properly with d3. I am using a linear scale but I can only see the first and last tick but nothing in between. The labels are being shown in between but not the tick marks.

What would cause this?

Comment: After inspecting it more, I see it creates the line element for the tick but only gives it the x2 and y2 attributes. It's missing the x1 and y1 attribute. Anyone know why that might be?

Comment: Did you set `.innerTickSize` (`.tickSizeInner` in d3 v4)?